# How to Make Fixed Labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am working in quarter sections of land and I want the labels of each section to be fixed. That is, I want it to be in the same location no matter if I zoom in or out of the map. Is there a way to do this on QGIS?

I want the labels to look like this:

[image]

But when I change the scale it moves around:

[image]

Comment: Which placement settings do you use? Did you try some settings?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the label properties go to "Placement" and move the checkmark to "whole polygon":

[image]

Alternatively you can also define a fixed coordinate for the label placement, either via geometry generator or data defined positioning:

[image]